# How to modify the number of columns in a poster under scrartcl document class

Tags: koma-script

I am using the `scrartcl` document class to produce a poster for a conference presentation.

The number of columns set at the beginning of the document is four, but I would like to use four just for the upper part of the poster and then modify the number of the columns, for example two or three, for the lower part.

In any case there seems to be no change in doing that.

Comment: The answer to the not asked question is probably: Use `multicol` (and perhaps one of the classes/packages more suitable for posters)!